# "Explorer" window not visible in Visual Studio

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am learning the basics of Django on a Windows 10 system. The video tutorials I am working through use Visual Studio as the development environment – I’m sure they are many other equally capable IDEs. I am currently just working through exercises that will run the code on a server on the Windows 10 machine. I installed VS 2019 Community edition on my Windows 10 machine about a year ago for other study. I have probably adjusted some settings which were needed at the time. Now, the tutorials I am following, when the tutor drags into VS a directory containing various Django-related files such as Python scripts, the “Explorer” windows shows the directory and sub-directory hierarchy as if I was looking at the directory through Windows Explorer or other file manager. Now on my VS2019 I cannot see the Explorer window. I can open the files, but I don’t know which directories they are in which makes the video tutorials difficult to follow. How can I reinstate the VS Explorer window? I have searched for an answer but I am probably not phrasing the question correctly.

Thanks,

Clive

Comment: Menu item -> `View->Solution Explorer` ? Is that the window you want put back? .. and "I’m sure there are many other equally capable IDEs".. no, not in my opinion.  I use xcode (hate it), and often the JetBrains stuff (very good.. just IMHO not AS GOOD).  Free ones like Eclipse, KDevelop, etc etc all work.. I guess better than having no IDE at all.   IDEs are like a religion though, people like what they were brought up on. ;)

Comment: @Señor CMasMas. I tried Menu item -> View->Solution Explorer but the presentation of files and folder hierarchies was difficult to follow and use. Maybe this could be configured but I couldn't find out how. I decided to perform a "repair install" of VS2019 which reset all user settings. Now when I open a folder in VS the Solution Explorer presents the folders and files in a clear hierarchy. Thanks for your suggestion and time. It put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I performed a "repair installation" of VS 2019, to remove all my forgotten customizations of VS. Then after repair completed the Solution Explorer, as suggested by Señor CMasMas, worked fine to show all the folders and hierarchies for my application.